# Awk insert text from a file before 2 specific lines

Tags: awk

I have 2 files, file1 and file2.

```
# cat /tmp/file1
***** insert new text ****

# cat /tmp/file2

</table>
some text
</table>
<table name="test" description="test line">
some text
```

I want to insert the text from file1 into file2 but only before the following 2 lines:

```
</table>
<table name="test" description="test line">
```

So the end result is:

```
</table>
some text
*** insert new text ****
</table>
<table name="test" description="test line">
some text
```

Here is the awk statement/commands I am trying, but the problem is awk is inserting the new text for each match.

```
# f1="$(</tmp/file1)"
# awk -vf1="$f1" '/<\/table>/,/<table name="test" description="test line">/{print f1;print;next}1' /tmp/file2

***** insert new text ****
</table>
***** insert new text ****
some text
***** insert new text ****
</table>
***** insert new text ****
<table name="test" description="test line">
some text
```

How do I fix the awk statement to only insert the text from file1 before those specific 2 lines? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works for me:

```
awk '{if(p=="</table>"&&$0=="<table name=\"test\" description=\"test line\">")
{system("cat file1");}if(p){print p}; p=$0}END{print $0}' file2
```

The if statement check if the current line matches `<table...>` and the previous line `</table>`. If yes, the contents of `file1` is printed, else the line in file2 is printed.

Comment: I think that's the way to go too, no doubt @EdMorton will have some neat method to amaze us...

Comment: This almost works but I am missing the line which contains "description= test line" in the output.

Comment: @user117974 There was a mistake, I changed my answer, try again please.